# Adding stripe to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, architecture, stripe-payments

For my rails app, there are two parts.

1) The actual site/app.

2) Site for businesses to pay to advertise.

The app is already built. It's a simple crud system using devise for user logins. I'm not using SSL for this.

For the business site, I simply want to have a form to enter in billing info and to be able to create an account. For the payments, I would like to use stripe. So, this site needs SSL. I would like this site to be on a subdomain of the same domain the app is on. So the main app is on example.com and the business site is on business.example.com.

**Should I split these into two different apps? If they should be one app, how do I get the separate site to point to the subdomain and use SSL? Do I create a separate devise login system as well?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Should I split these into two different apps?***

You can, but it's not necessary. However, because your users will presumably be the same across the actual site and the business site, it'd be simpler to utilize a single app, rather than persisting the same users across two apps.

***If they should be one app, how do I get the separate site to point to the subdomain and use SSL?***

There's some fairly complex logic involved with accomplishing this, including making modifications to your hosts file, middleware, and routes. I've found [this Ryan Bates' tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?view=asciicast) to be very helpful in setting up my own multi-subdomain installations.

As far as SSL goes, you'll need to configure this in both your Rails app as well as on your production server. You're evidently [working with Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689368/sub-domain-in-rails-app), so you may benefit from reading [Heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint) on setting up SSL on their end.

From a Rails perspective, a simpler ground-based approach towards enabling SSL may be to specify that *all* routes be SSL encrypted:

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :sessions, :constraints => { :protocol => "https" }
end
```

Alternatively, you can declare specific routes to be encrypted:

```
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do
  scope :constraints => { :protocol => "https" } do 
    # All your SSL routes.
  end
end
```

You can also look at [`force_ssl`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html) to protect controller access on an action-by-action basis.

***Do I create a separate devise login system as well?***

If you're running on a single app, then you can utilize a single Devise installation. This presumes, of course, that the users of your actual site will also be users of your business site.

Comment: Thanks you so much for taking the time to write out a very thoughtful, well written and extremely helpful response. You're awesome! :)